# Using non-default constructor when adding a new element in a vector of <class> objects

Tags: c++, stdvector

In a class, I have a vector of objects from a different class, like this:

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<Bar> barObject;
...
};
```

The class Bar defines a default constructor (all private variables initialize to zero), and a non-default constructor in which values can be fed in, as in:

```
Bar newBar(var1, var2);
```

In class Foo, the barObject vector is declared without specifying a size.

I'm guessing that if I want to use the default constructor, I can just do:

```
barObject.resize(barObject.size()+1);
```

And then alter the private variables of barObject i in the vector something like:

```
barObject.at(i).SetVar(value)
```

But if I want to use the non-default constructor and feed in values of the private variables, would I be able to just do something like:

```
barObject.insert(i, tempBar);
```

With tempBar being an object of class Bar that has the private values I want at position i of vector barObject?

Comment: Too little code accompanying the prose. Please make as much of a [mcve] as you can.

Comment: @Yunnosch Lots of code != better question. It's not always black and white.

Comment: @Rakete1111 True, but describing code (while useful) would be nicely augmented by showing the code.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah, I guess that's true. :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't test your idea?

Comment: if you already resized the vector you dont need to insert, just assign: `barObject[i] = tempBar;`, though thats not the most efficient way to initialize a vector

Comment: @tobi303 OP wants to use `iterator` which is `std::vector<Bar>::iterator`, you suggest him to use `iterator` in `operator[]` which use `size_type`. It's different things.

Comment: @StahlRat where do you read that `i` is `std::vector<Bar>::iterator` ? OP merely says that they want to place `tempBar` at position `i` and just one line of code before the `insert` there is `at(i)` which would imply `i` being `size_t`. I know that it is not consistent, but I doubt that using an iterator is the critical point here

Answer (score 2):

`resize` has an overload:

`void resize (size_type n, const value_type& val);`

This allows you to specify the value in newly allocated memory.  However, if you want to allocate the vector as part of construction, you can do that as well.  The vector has a constructor to do this:

```
vector (size_type n, const value_type& val,
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Then all you must do is use uniform initialization syntax to construct the vector just once:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : barObject(17, Bar(4, 5)) {} // Creates a 17 length array
};
```

If you just want to use your already constructed `vector` and add elements to the end of it you can use `push_back` or `emplace_back`.

In order to use insert you're going to need to make an iterator to the location of insertion:

```
auto myIt = barObject.begin() + 3;
myIt = barObject.insert(myIt, 5, Bar(6, 7)); // Inserts 5 objects at offset 3, and increases its size by 5.
myIt += 6;
myIt = barObject.insert(myIt, Bar(8, 7)); // Inserts 1 object at offset 9 (not offset 14), and increases its size by 1.
```

In order to change a value within a vector you can use either the `at()` function or the `operator[]` function:

```
barObject.at(3) = Bar(4, 5);
barObject[3] = Bar(4, 5);
```

The difference between the two is `.at()` does bounds checking.  Whereas `operator[]` does not.

Answer (score -1):

Answering on your question. Yes, you can do that kind of insert:

```
barObject.insert(i, tempBar);
```

Just make sure that iterator `i` is valid one:

```
std::vector<Bar>::iterator i = barObject.begin();
barObject.insert(i, tempBar);
```

Comment: @Mooing Duck vector::insert uses iterators